# How do I change nav-justified border color from bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am using nav-justified and nav tabs (together) from bootstrap 3. The border is way too light for me and I'd like to make it thicker or change the color.

First I tried

```
.nav-justified
{
border: 4px solid black;
}
```

Issue with this is that the whole space of my tabs are getting outlined.

Next I tried

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>.active>a
{
    border: 4px solid black;
}
```

Nope, it just does it by default but any changed to the tab (switching for example) erases that border.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your style.css is added to you html doc after the bootstrap style sheet otherwise it will not override bootstrap styles. Next have a look at the nav boarder using a developer tool. Chrome has a really nice one, right click on the nav bar and choose inspect element. This will give you a list of what styles are active and what styles are being over written. Give you nav bar an id e.g id="myNav" then override the css by using #mynav .nav-justified{ 
my styles}. If you can post your html that would help.